# how can I get connect-assets to recompile my coffee files when they change?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, node.js-connect, connect-assets

Related, but hoping for a lower friction answer: [How do I use Node and Express with coffeescript and requirejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545022/how-do-i-use-node-and-express-with-coffeescript-and-requirejs)

I've got connect-assets set up so that I can have .js and .coffee files side by side in my /assets/js folder. Only problem: I have to re-get the page containing any compiled coffee files whenever those files change. Minor problem I guess, but I've been doing a lot of CURL on the files themselves as part of troubleshooting -- doing a CURL on the coffee js file itself won't cause it to be recompiled.

Does connect-assets have any sort of 'watch' feature? Couldn't find one in the [docs](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets). Do I have to just put a `coffee -bcw *.coffee` running in that directory?

Edit: In the end I just used grunt to recompile on change. That's worked much better than connect-assets. I'll leave this question here because it's got some views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking 100%, but have you considered using something like [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor)? This can watch CoffeeScript files (and other resources) and restart your node process when they're modified. I've used it with connect-assets successfully.

Comment: See the "Edit" above, I added that a few days ago

Comment: Sure. I figured you were leaving the problem up so that in case someone had a similar issue, they could find solutions here, so I offered a solution with that in mind.

Comment: Yeah that's sorta what I'm doing, but I was looking for a connect-assets specific solution without adding in another tool. In the end I just added in another tool but I wonder if I just wasn't using connect-assets correctly.