# How do I use Jade's CoffeeScript filters in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, pug

I'm having difficulty understanding how filters are implemented in Express/Jade. Most results I find use a much older version of Express and/or Jade, which has been long deprecated. I have some code that needs to be placed inline in my Jade webpage. However, when I go and run the Express server I run this page on, the inline `:coffee-script` filter is rendered as text, as seen here: [Page Render](https://i.imgur.com/Ml8TXpW.png).

Here's my `index.jade` page:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    link(href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet")
  body
    .container
      h1 Denon AVR X1000 remote
      .row
        .col-md-3
          h2 Status
          dl.horizontal
            dt Connected
            dd#data-connected Not connected

            dt Power
            dd#data-power ...

            dt Input
            dd#data-input ...

            dt Volume
            dd(id="data-volume") ...

        .col-md-9
          h2#data-info-title ...
          pre#data-info

  script(src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js")
  script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")


  :coffee-script
    Denon = do ->
      connect: (host, port)->
        # connect to the device
        socket.emit 'denon.connect', { host: host, port: port }

      command: (cmd, params)->
        # turn the device on
        socket.emit 'denon.command', { cmd: cmd, params: params or [] }

      exec: (cmd, params)->
        # turn the device on
        socket.emit 'denon.exec', { cmd: cmd, param: param or "" }

    socket = io.connect 'http://localhost'
    socket.on 'connect', (data)->
      Denon.connect '192.168.0.31', 23

    socket.on 'denon.connected', (data)->
      console.log 'denon.connected!'

      $("#data-connected").text "Connected" 

      # get power state and info
      Denon.command 'power'
      Denon.command 'input'
      Denon.command 'volume'
      Denon.command 'info'


    socket.on 'denon.response', (data)->
      switch data.cmd
        when 'power' then $("#data-power").text data.value   
        when 'input' then $("#data-input").text data.value
        when 'volume' then $("#data-volume").text data.value
        when 'info'
          for index, value of data.value
            # clear on new data and change title
            if index is "0"
              $("#data-info").empty()
              $("#data-info-title").text value
            # just append data
            else
              $("#data-info").append "#{value}\n"
        else
          console.log 'response', data
```

And here's my `server.coffee` page, which initializes the Express server:

```
# denon instances
dcon = new (require './lib/connection')
dcmd = new (require './lib/commands')(dcon)

# webserver
filters = require 'jade-filters'
bodyParser = require 'body-parser'
express = require 'express'
app = express()
server = require('http').createServer(app)
io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
app.use bodyParser.json()
app.use bodyParser.urlencoded(extended: true)
app.use express.static 'views'

app.get '/', (req, res)-> res.render 'index'

server.listen(8000)
console.log("Now listening on port 8000...")

# socket.io
io.sockets.on 'connection', (socket)->
  # connect to the receiver
  socket.on 'denon.connect', (data)->
    dcon.connect data.host, data.port, ->
      socket.emit 'denon.connected'

  # call command methods
  socket.on 'denon.command', (data)->
    if dcmd[data.cmd]
      dcmd[data.cmd].apply dcmd, data.params or []

  # send core command
  socket.on 'denon.exec', (data)->
    dcon.send data.command, data.param

  # push response to the client
  dcon.response (cmd, value)->
    socket.emit 'denon.response', cmd: cmd, value: value
```

Doing some more research (finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545022/how-do-i-use-node-and-express-with-coffeescript-and-requirejs)), I can only conclude one (or more) of the following:

- My Express server isn't working as an Express server, making the `:coffee-script` filter non-functional.
- I need to install another dependency to make the filter work.

**Is there something I'm missing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include it in a `script` tag:

```
script
  :coffee-script
    console.log 'This is coffee script'
```

Reference: http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/

Comment: Oh wow, I thought that the `:coffee-script` acted as the `script` tag! This correctly renders the code. Thanks!